# Can't find myself in the User Reputation Leagues

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

Can't find myself in the User Reputation Leagues when select ["Week"](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/355/week/ru-stackoverflow) tab:

> [image: week]

Even when I type a name:

> [image: no users]

If I choose another tab, e.g. ["Month"](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/355/month/ru-stackoverflow), then can see my profile on the first line:

> [image: month]

Why I can't see myself in the Week tab? Is it a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: The date range is Dec 4-5, so it excludes your +10 on the 6th. Not sure why that is, but I assume it's not updated constantly.

Comment: @NathanTuggy is user not showed in the list if he have no rep changes in selected range?

Comment: No, why would they be? Tons and tons of users coast in any given time period, especially short periods like a week.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I thought that I can see myself always, even if I didn't have any rep changes.

Comment: There are only [253 users listed for the week](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/355/week/ru-stackoverflow/2016-12-04?sort=reputationchange&page=6), out of 2520 total users that can ever be listed (200+ rep), so it's clear that that's not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no reputation events for the time shown.

According to your screenshots, the current "Week" view currently shows December 4th to December 5th. You earned no reputation for those two days on that site, so you aren't listed in the league. You *did* earn reputation December 3rd, so you *do* show up for the month tab.

Through digging, I see that users showing as "0 reputation" for a period in the league *do* have reputation activities recorded, however they even out to 0. On Stack Overflow, I appear on neither the Month nor Week tabs, as I have no reputation events there.

Once the league updates with today's reputation gain, you'll be able to find yourself in the league list just fine.

Comment: If anyone's wondering how I'm sure of this, I just dug through a page and a half (about 75) users marked "0 reputation" for Dec 4 and 5 on Stack Overflow's league, and all 75 of them confirm what I've laid out in my answer. All of them have rep changes for those two days that even out to 0 total reputation.